# Unit Test mongoDb with .net core

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, unit-testing, .net-core

I am trying to write down unit test for my repository which is interacting with MongoDb but facing a problem/exception in mocking the objects. This is what I have tried so far;

This is how my class looks like i.e. I have create a repository class and extend it from interface;

```
public class UserManagementRepository : IUserManagementRepository
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<UserModel> _users;
    public UserManagementRepository(IDatabaseSettings dbSettings, IApplicationSettings applicationSettings, IMongoClient mongoClient)
    {
        IMongoDatabase database = mongoClient.GetDatabase(dbSettings.DatabaseName);
        _users = database.GetCollection<UserModel>(applicationSettings.UserCollectionName);
    }
    
    public async Task<GeneralResponse> Get(string id)
    {
        GeneralResponse response = new GeneralResponse();
        try
        {
            IAsyncCursor<UserModel> userModel = await _users.FindAsync(user => user.Id == id);
            if (userModel != null)
            {
                response.Message = "User exists!";
                response.Data = userModel.FirstOrDefault();
                response.ResponseCode = ResponseCode.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                response.Message = $"User with Id: {id} not found!";
                response.ResponseCode = ResponseCode.Success;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Message = "Failure";
            response.ResponseCode = ResponseCode.Error;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

This is how my Test class look like

```
public class UserManagmentRepositoryTests
{
    private Mock<IDatabaseSettings> _mockDbSettings;
    private Mock<IApplicationSettings> _mockApplicationSettings;
    private Mock<IMongoClient> _mockClient;
    public UserManagmentRepositoryTests()
    {
        _mockDbSettings = new Mock<IDatabaseSettings>();
        _mockApplicationSettings = new Mock<IApplicationSettings>();
        _mockClient = new Mock<IMongoClient>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetUserWithId_Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var repo = new Mock<IUserManagementRepository>();
        IDatabaseSettings dbSettings = new DatabaseSettings()
        {
            ConnectionString = "mongodb:connectionstring",
            DatabaseName = "dbname"
        };
        _mockDbSettings.Setup(x => x).Returns(dbSettings);

        IApplicationSettings applicationSettings = new ApplicationSettings() { UserCollectionName = "users" };
        _mockApplicationSettings.Setup(app => applicationSettings).Returns(applicationSettings);

        MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(dbSettings.ConnectionString);
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
        _mockClient.Setup(c => client);

        var ctr = new UserManagementRepository(_mockDbSettings.Object, _mockApplicationSettings.Object, _mockClient.Object);

        // Act
        var result = ctr.Get("132");

        // Assert
        //result.StatusCode.Should().NotBeNull();
    }
}
```

I get an exception on every setup

[image: Exception]

Comment: note: it's not recommended to mock something that you don't own. You should mock your wrapper over mongoClient ie your repository

Comment: @dododo Yes you are right I do not own mongoClient but I own IDatabaseSettings and IApplicationSettings.

Comment: ` _mockClient.Setup(c => client);` - I doubt you can do it in this way, since `Setup` implies configuring behavior for methods inside IMongoClient, not IMongoClient itself, so you can't provide a client as argument

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `ApplicationSettings` as an expression. The setup method expects you to provide an expression for when to activate the mocked override.

In your case just get rid of the `Mock<IApplicationSettings>` altogether and mock all the objects you need to call any methods on:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task GetUserWithId_Test()
{
  // Arrange
  var userModel = new UserModel() { Id = "123" };

  var mockCursor = new Mock<IAsyncCursor<UserModel>>();
  mockCursor
    .Setup(c => c.FirstOrDefault())
    .Returns(userModel);

  var mockCollection = new Mock<IMongoCollection<UserModel>>();
  Predicate<UserModel> filter = u => u.Id == userModel.Id;
  mockCollection
    .Setup(c => c.FindAsync(filter))
    .ReturnsAsync(mockCursor.Object);

  var mockDb = new Mock<IMongoDatabase>();
  mockDb
    .Setup(db => db.GetCollection<UserModel>(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(mockCollection.Object);

  _mockClient
    .Setup(c => c.GetDatabase(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(mockDb.Object)

  var ctr = new UserManagementRepository(new(), new(), _mockClient.Object);

  // Act
  var result = ctr.Get("132");

  // Assert
  result.StatusCode.Should().Be(ResponseCode.Success);
  result.Message.Should().Be("User exists!");
  result.Data.Should().Be(userModel);
}
```

Hope this helps a little

Comment: An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments. I faced this earlier and again facing this as the statement is clear.

Comment: @J.SMTBCJ15 If there are optional arguments in any of the mocked methods, you have to provide them in the Setup calls as well. I don't know your methods' signature, you have to check for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To use your ApplicationSettings as mocked ApplicationSettings, you must use an expression in the setup method.

Instead of:

```
    IApplicationSettings applicationSettings = new ApplicationSettings() { UserCollectionName = "users" };
    _mockApplicationSettings.Setup(app => applicationSettings).Returns(applicationSettings);
```

Use e.g. this:

```
    IApplicationSettings applicationSettings = new ApplicationSettings() { UserCollectionName= "users" };
    _mockApplicationSettings.Setup(app => app.UserCollectionName).Returns(applicationSettings.UserCollectionName);
```

---

Edit: Complete Example

```
    private Mock<IDatabaseSettings> _mockDbSettings;
    private Mock<IApplicationSettings> _mockApplicationSettings;
    private Mock<IMongoClient> _mockClient;
    public UserManagmentRepositoryTests()
    {
        _mockDbSettings = new Mock<IDatabaseSettings>();
        _mockApplicationSettings = new Mock<IApplicationSettings>();
        _mockClient = new Mock<IMongoClient>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetUserWithId_Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var repo = new Mock<IUserManagementRepository>();
        IDatabaseSettings dbSettings = new DatabaseSettings()
        {
            ConnectionString = "mongodb:connection",
            DatabaseName = "dbname"
        };
        _mockDbSettings.Setup(x => x.ConnectionString).Returns(dbSettings.ConnectionString);
        _mockDbSettings.Setup(x => x.DatabaseName).Returns(dbSettings.DatabaseName);

        IApplicationSettings applicationSettings = new ApplicationSettings() { UserCollectionName = "users" };
        _mockApplicationSettings.Setup(app => app.UserCollectionName).Returns(applicationSettings.UserCollectionName);

        MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(dbSettings.ConnectionString);
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
        _mockClient.Setup(c => c.GetDatabase(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<MongoDatabaseSettings>()))
                    .Returns <string, MongoDatabaseSettings>((name, settings) => client.GetDatabase(name, settings));

        var ctr = new UserManagementRepository(_mockDbSettings.Object, _mockApplicationSettings.Object, _mockClient.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await ctr.Get("132");

        // Assert
        result.ResponseCode.Should().NotBe(ResponseCode.Error);
    }
```

Comment: I already tried that same error.

Comment: Did you also changed the lines for setting up the database settings and the mongo client?

Comment: yes .. same problem for all of 3 setups

Answer (score -1):

I see no reason mocking IApplicationSettings and IDatabaseSettings you should go with :

```
 public class UserManagmentRepositoryTests
{
    private Mock<IMongoClient> _mockClient;
    public UserManagmentRepositoryTests()
    {
        _mockClient = new Mock<IMongoClient>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetUserWithId_Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var repo = new Mock<IUserManagementRepository>();
        IDatabaseSettings dbSettings = new DatabaseSettings()
        {
            ConnectionString = "mongodb:connectionstring",
            DatabaseName = "dbname"
        };

        IApplicationSettings applicationSettings = new ApplicationSettings() { UserCollectionName = "users" };

        MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(dbSettings.ConnectionString);
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
        _mockClient.Setup(c => client);

        var ctr = new UserManagementRepository(dbSettings, applicationSettings, _mockClient.Object);

        // Act
        var result = ctr.Get("132");

        // Assert
        //result.StatusCode.Should().NotBeNull();
    }
}
```